# How can a program enforce that one of two authorities to sign a transaction?

Tags: anchor, rust, pda

I know I can pass in a Context to my instruction and the struct looks something like:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ListOfAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub ONE: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub TWO: AccountInfo<'info>,

    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"seed", ONE.key().as_ref()], bump = pda.bump)]
    pub PDA: Account<'info, T>,
}
```

I want both ONE and TWO to be able to call the same instruction (I can make two but it'll have the same code). Can I allow both ONE and TWO to be a signer? ONE's pubkey is used as a seed for PDA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `#[account(signer)]` or `Signer<T>` to do this which would be the usual Anchor ways. However, `AccountInfo` tells you if the account is a signer, you can check this as part of your instruction.

```
require!(ctx.accounts.ONE.is_signer || ctx.accounts.TWO.is_signer);
```

Comment: Thanks!! note: it seems that require!() also needs an error as a parameter ```require!(ctx.accounts.ONE.is_signer || ctx.accounts.TWO.is_signer, Error:MissingRequiredSignature);```